# Return one element array or empty array best practice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any better way to implement this?

```
const a = _.get(obj, 'property');
const b = a ? [a] : [];
```

`obj` is an object, may or may not have `property`. If it does, return an array of one element of `property`, else return an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const obj = {
  prop: "hello"
}

const b = obj.hasOwnProperty("prop") ? [obj.prop] : [];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {}
console.log("when property is not present: ", obj["property"] || [])

obj = {property: ["hello"]}

console.log("when property is present: ", obj["property"] || [])
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite right, cos if the property exists they want **an array containing that property**, not just the property itself. In your answer they'd only get the property.

Comment: please, feel free to make an edit to this ans or posting your version of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it into array an filter non-nil value

```
const a = _.get(obj, 'property');
const b = [a].filter(Boolean);
```

```js
const a1 = null
const a2 = 1

const res1 = [a1].filter(Boolean)
const res2 = [a2].filter(Boolean)

console.log(res1)
console.log(res2)
```